# Disabling "Connect to open networks"

Tags: android, android-wifi

I want to *programmatically* switch on/off `Connect to open networks` and `Open network notification` from the android settings:
https://source.android.com/devices/tech/connect/wifi-infrastructure

How can I do this? Do I have to use `ConnectivityManager` / `WifiManager`?

The reason for this is that I am annoyed by my phone telling me about "open" telekom wifi/hotspot when I am outside. Also I cannot find the settings page to turn these settings off on my Samsung Galaxy S7.

**Update**

As I have not found a viable solution programatically I have solved the problem the following way:
Remove public hotpots that I do not want to connect to from my "Saved WiFi Network" list. Use MacroDroid/Tasker to disable WiFi when I am leaving my home.

Comment: Try action "android.settings.WIFI_IP_SETTINGS" to start this wifi settings activity?

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp This opens the wifi settings page which I can also access in the samsung settings. There is no option `Connect to open networks` on my Galaxy S7. On the S9 there seems to be this option in this menu. But this does not help me with my S7.

Comment: I found that, your device must support network score , So that you could tell wether this network should be connected . http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/wifi/UseOpenWifiPreferenceController.java#66 check this link.

Comment: You can try "adb shell dumpsys network_score" , My output is "scoring is disabled" , So I can't find the connect to open networks.

Comment: @ihsan.gaozp For my device it actually returns scoring information. The value for all networks is -128 though.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you can disable `Open network notification`:

```
Settings.Secure.putInt(cr, Settings.Secure.WIFI_NETWORKS_AVAILABLE_NOTIFICATION_ON, 0);
```

But therefore you need the permission `android.permission.WRITE_SECURE_SETTINGS` which is only available to system apps.